# How to access docker container at digitalocean?

Tags: docker, digital-ocean

When I run following commands, I can access **127.0.0.1:80** at localhost successfully.

```
docker run -p 127.0.0.1:80:80 --name Mynginx -dt nginx
docker exec -it Mynginx bash
```

But If I run the commands at digitalocean's DROPLETS, how to access it now? ( I tried to access **DROPLETS's IP address:80**, but I get nothing.)

Comment: How are you running it?  Do you have something like a `docker run` command, or some DO equivalent?  Please add the relevant details to the question.

Comment: @DavidMaze Hello, I edit my question. Please have a look.

Answer (score 2):

You need to `EXPOSE` the port. See the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose) for more information on how.

### Running from the command-line

If you run the containers from the command-line, you can map the ports with the -p tag. You can map multiple ports.

```
docker run -dt -p 80:80 --name Mynginx nginx
```

or

```
docker run -dt -p 80:80 -p 443:443 --name Mynginx nginx
```

### Docker-compose

If you're using docker-compose, you can add the `EXPOSE` tag in your yaml file.

```
version: '2.3'
services:
  my_container:
    container_name: "Mynginx"
    image: nginx:latest
    expose:
      - "80"
```

Comment: Updated - you can then access it by the IP as normal.

Answer (score 2):

You need to update your droplets firewall settings to allow incoming connections to port `:80`. To update this select your droplet.

Then go to `Networking` -> `Manage Firewalls` -> `Create Firewall`

Then under `Inbound Rules` create a new `HTTP` rule by selecting `HTTP` from the dropdown menu. Scroll down and apply this firewall to your droplet, then you should be able to receive inbound traffic on port `:80`. You will have to add a similar rule for any other ports you want to open up.

See [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/docs/networking/firewalls/how-to/configure-rules/) for more details.